# What can facilitate this tedious/repetitive process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

Just some quick background: We have a text file that stores several KPIs; for example, one line says *KPI_One*, so I read (and process) X amount of lines until I've read all the data for that KPI. This is done with several KPIs. There's no relationship between the KPIs and each KPI has a different format.

Anyways, I'm already reading the file and processing every line accordingly. The problem is that there are tons of KPIs, so for each, there has to be a table, a stored procedure to store, and another one to retrieve. In the C# code, every KPI has a class with a struct, a method that parses the string, another one that inserts the parsed line, and one that retrieves the data.

So as you can see, every KPI requires 6 different steps and it becomes tedious. My question: is there a way to globalize all of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of some lines that you parse please? I have an idea but I'm not sure it would fit your problem

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to simplify the whole problem.

1. we want to store all the KPI data in a single table seamlessly, and not create/maintain N tables, corresponding stored procs etc.
2. we will use 1 stored proc to insert the data and 1 to read it for all KPI data. (we can eliminate stored proc completely, by using Linq1Sql or EF)
3. we'll have a single programming construct to handle all types of KPIs and their data.

**one solution:**

'KPI' Table columns are:

1. Id
2. Name
3. JsonLineData

C# Code:

```
public enum KPIType
{
 None = 0,
 KPI_One = 1,  // the value corresponds to the Id column values in KPI table.
 KPI_Two = 2,
 // so on
}

Dictionary<KPIType, Func<string, string>> kpiProcessors = 
                         new Dictionary<KPIType, Func<string, string>>();

// define all the kpi processor delegates.
// the delegate will take string line data from the input file and 
// convert into the Struct object for that KPI and serialize this struct 
// into JSON.
// note the output string is not same as the input file string. it is JSON
// of the structure for the KPI.

kpiProcessors.Add(KPIType.KPI_One, KPIOneDataProcessorMethodName);
kpiProcessors.Add(KPIType.KPI_Two, KPITwoDataProcessorMethodName);

// KPIOneDataProcessorMethodName is of the form
public string KPIOneDataProcessorMethodName(string inputFileKpiLineData) 
{
 struct KPI_One_Struct; 
 // process inputFileKpiLineData to populate KPI_One_Struct
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(KPI_One_Struct);
}

void ProcessFile()
{
// actual file processing logic.

do
{
    KPIType currentKPIType = KPI_One; // read current KPI;

    while (string lineData = KPI_Type_Line_Data_From_File)
    {
       Func<string, string> kpiFunc = kpiProcessors[currentKPIType];   
       string jsonKpiStructData = kpiFunc(lineData);

       SQLHelper.InsertKpiDataLine(currentKPIType, jsonKpiStructData);
    }

} while (kpidataisreadfromfile)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a few questions: 1) What elements would the struct include? 2) When I retrieve the values, I would need to deserialize the JSON object? 3) There's a method called KPIOneDataProcessorMethodName, Is there going to be a method for each KPI? 4) This data is stored in an hourly basis. One of the tables for one of the KPIs has 44K records in 18 days. Assuming I store everything in one table, would this be faster or slower than parsing it and storing it in its respective table?

Comment: I was hoping for a more object-oriented approach for this. Regardless of the architecture I use, I would still need to store the data parsed since I'lb aggregating it.